# Update huge SQLite databases

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have two `SQLite` tables that are really huge (milions of rows with geometries inside). First one is doesn't change (records aren't updated etc.). The second one updates (the old records can be updated/removed, new ones can be added).

From time to time I need to update the 1st table using the 2nd one. Because it's so large amount of data, I have to detect changes made in the 2nd table and apply them into the 1st one. I also cannot do this in RAM, because tables contain geometries and they can be pretty heavy.

What is the possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution**: drop the first table then use expression like

```
drop table table1;
create table table1 as select * from table2;
```

**More complex solution**: use a pair of moving "cursors" - not database cursors as in Oracle, but just some variables containing table PK values.
Set both cursors to the lowest ID in both tables. Then, just follow simple rules:

1. If the record from table1 exists in table2 and is the same, skip, advance both cursors
2. If the record from table1 exists in table2 and is not the same, update record in table1, advance both cursors
3. If the record from table1 does not exist in table2, delete it, advance table1 cursor
4. If the record from table2 does not exist in table1, insert it, advance table2 cursor

This way you get linear O(N) algorithm with O(1) memory requirements (leaving aside DB operations complexity).